# How many ways are there to add up to certain number?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm working on a probability problem which involves several dice that must add up to a certain number. I'm trying to generalize the problem:

**Problem**: Given a value $t \in \mathbb{N}$, how many ways do we have to pick $k$ numbers of the set $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ such that its sum adds up to $t$. That is to say, I want to find an expression of the cardinal of the set
$$\left\lbrace(x_1, x_2, ..., x_k) \in \{1, 2, \dots, n\}^k : \sum_{i=1}^k x_i = t \right\rbrace.$$

I write it this way so it is clear that we can repeat numbers and that the order matters, (i.e., $1 + 2$ and $2 + 1$ would count as different ways of addint up to $3$).

**My approach**: I'm considering the polynomial
$$(x + x^2 + \dots + x^n)^k$$
and I'm trying to find an expression for the coefficient of $x^t$ in the expansion of the above expression.

I've tried to rewrite the polynomial as
$$\left( \frac{x-x^{n+1}}{1-x} \right)^k,$$
but I don't know how to continue.

There is a way of determine this ammount?

Comment: "*Stars and bars*" combined with inclusion-exclusion to handle the condition that no number should exceed $n$.  The general term will look particularly ugly if you insist on writing it out.

Comment: For a specific case with easy to work with numbers, [see this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3324257/how-to-get-coefficient-with-t10-in-1tt2t3t4t510/3324261#3324261).  For the most general form, [see this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1653780/possible-ways-to-have-n-bounded-natural-numbers-with-a-fixed-sum/1653839#1653839).